# How to remove HeadlessChrome Log messages from my Karma logs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, zone.js

I'm running an Angular app and my unit tests are workingas expected though every time I run the tests I get all this warnings:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '', 'Error: STACKTRACE TRACKING'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '', 'Error: STACKTRACE TRACKING'

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '', 'Error: STACKTRACE TRACKING'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)'

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:39:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:39:1)'

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:39:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at new LongStackTrace (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:33:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at new LongStackTrace (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:33:1)'

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at new LongStackTrace (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:33:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at captureStackTraces (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:128:1)'
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at captureStackTraces (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:128:1)'

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '>>>>>>', '    at __SEP_TAG__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:993:1)', '    at captureStackTraces (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/vassilis/Projects/Client-Portal-FE/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js:128:1)'
```

Here's my Karma configuration as well:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    concurrency: Infinity,
    files: [
      { pattern: 'node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js', included: true, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css', included: true, watched: true },
    ]
  });
};
```

I would really love to remove those log messages from my terminal.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing only mine starts with: Chrome 61.0.3163 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) LOG: '...' and my tests are failing.

Answer (score 2):

for the future readers add this to your karma configuration:

```
        browserConsoleLogOptions: {
        level: 'warn',
        format: '%b %T: %m',
        terminal: false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try to remove `long-stack-trace-zone.js` from `polyfill.ts` when you run karma test.